# android kotlin java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/number.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, permission-denied

I'm writing an app for Android 10 using kotlin.
The app has to read file named `number.txt` from internal storage.

But it always fails to do so:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/number.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Here what I have in my manifest:

```xml
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

I have to only read the file, so there is no write permission in manifest.

Here is my code, as you can see I use runtime permissions:

This is the function that requests permission and if it granted, reads the file:

```kotlin
    private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val path = "/storage/emulated/0"
            val file = File("$path/number.txt")
            val pln = file.readText()
            plnText.text = pln
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 101)
        }
    }
```

Then I call `setupPermissions` in my `onCreate` method.

That's it, I don't understand why isn't it working.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I don't know what is the reason, but I just changed my code to this:

```kotlin
if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    val file = File("/storage/emulated/0/number.txt")
    val pln = file.readText()
    Log.i("IKO_APP", pln)
//  plnText.text = path.toString()
}
```

And it works without any error! I'm wondering though why?

Comment: How did you put that file there?

Comment: Just created it in internal storage

Comment: For that you need write permission. How could your app do without?

Comment: It's not my app it's me who created it

Comment: And you are not going to tell how i understand.

Comment: What do you mean? I  created the file with application that is called QuickEdit.

Comment: @blackapps is asking how your app managed to write a file if it can't read it, but it sounds like you created it with something else so mystery solved!

Comment: My app didn't managed to write any file! I created it myself and want to read it with my app. That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Android 10, you can add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest. This opts you into the legacy storage model, and your external storage code should work.

And for read operations, you should be able to still do what you are doing on Android 11+, courtesy of the "raw paths" change, even after you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 30 or higher.

However, for *write* operations, you have until the second half of 2021 to switch to something else:

- Use methods on `Context`, such as `getExternalFilesDir()`, to get at directories on external storage into which your app can write. You do not need any permissions to use those directories on Android 4.4+. However, the data that you store there gets removed when your app is uninstalled.
- Use the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.
- If your content is media, you can use `MediaStore` to place the media in standard media locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my manifest, unfortunately it didn't helped, any ideas on how to solve this? Also for my app I don't need to write anything.

Comment: @Acmpo6ou: Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` instead of your hard-coded directory.

Comment: On Android 11 devices the normal directories like Download, Documents, DCIM, Pictures, Alarms and so on are not only readable but writable too if targetting 30.

Comment: I've changed my hard-coded directory to `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` but for some reason it does not point to `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads`, it points to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mod.iko_mod/files/Download`. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: You are not using that was said to use.

Comment: Yes, because that was deprecated. In fact it looks pretty the same.

Comment: It does not matter that it is deprecated. It still works.

Comment: what is the point? `getExternalFilesDir()` works perfectly and it is not deprecated

Comment: @Acmpo6ou: "Is there a way to change this?" -- no, because that it where it is supposed to point. It also has the benefit of not requiring any permissions for you to use it.

Comment: But I was able to do it, I edited my question, wrote about that there