# Unable to open android's root folder

Tags: android, permissions

I want to make an explorer app. To give me a rough example I have the Simple File Manager app that shows my phone's file system :

[image]

[image]

I get the same result from my computer's file explorer when I plug the phone through USB :

[image]

So I have added a few permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And of course I made sure to ask the permissions to the user (although I'm not sure if I should ask for the Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission as well, I want to be able to write too, but the authorisation popup doesn't mention read/write, it just asks for access to the storage) :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
}
```

But then I'm trying to get the content of the root folder, the one on the screenshots, I've tried to open a few this way :

```
Environment.getDataDirectory().listFiles() // Is null
Environment.getRootDirectory().listFiles() // Isn't the correct folder
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles() // Null
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).listFiles() // Null
```

I have tried almost every interesting paths found on this gist (https://gist.github.com/lopspower/76421751b21594c69eb2), but none of them give me what I want...

Comment: My apologies, but what exactly your question? you want to access to the Root folder ?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the correct location. Bear in mind that [you need to modify your manifest to gain read access to that directory on Android 10+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64119463/115145) in addition to the permission bits that you have set up already.

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I'm trying to get the same list of files in the code as on the screenshots

Comment: @CommonsWare That was it, thank you very much ! But if I understood correctly this is the legacy system, what would be the correct way to have the same result ? I've tried with the Context object as well, with no result...

Comment: @MarkKeen Thank you very much, I'll read that, this system is a headache

Comment: "what would be the correct way to have the same result ?" -- as I wrote in that linked-to answer, "for read operations, you should be able to still do what you are doing on Android 11+, courtesy of the "raw paths" change, even after you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 30 or higher". If you are looking to do **write** operations as well... I recommend that you write some other app.

Comment: What do you mean to write some other app ?

Comment: Please do not just delete a post and then repost again a little bit different. You could have go on with the other one. Now info i told you about Android 11 is away.

Comment: Further: your results will depend on the Android version of used device. Mention it. Mention them.

Comment: @blackapps You told me to be precise....... Once I got more info I removed the old one to post a cleaner question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    Log.d("FILE", "--> "+file.getName());
                }
            }
```

Make sure the storage permission is granted, and add this line to your manifest :  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` within the App tag.

**Logcat :**

```
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Android
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> MIUI
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> dctp
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> did
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Movies
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> DCIM
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Pictures
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Download
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> WhatsApp
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> ClassicGames
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> .wallpaperboard
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> com.facebook.katana
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> FileExplorer
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> logger
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> .turing.dat
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> MicTest
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Telegram
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> IMG_20210206_210449.jpg
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> voip-data
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> Music
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> CamScanner
2021-02-27 23:55:35.470 3285-3285/maa.abc D/FILE: --> .BackgroundChange
```

Comment: Request legacy external is only for Android 10.